# Programmatically change variable from public to private

Tags: php

Is it possible for me to programmatically change a variable from public to private within a function call of a class?

Comment: Why would you want to? Use setters and getters.

Comment: I'm using getters/setters, but it's being implemented on an existing system that doesn't and I want to break the functionality of $object->var preferably with a simple loop through the $fields array which is used to determine the getters/setters

Comment: Are you in search of creating a Heisenproperty with unknown state?

Comment: It is possible with Reflection (ReflectionProperty::setAccessible) but as abloodywar above here says: You might want to think about alternatives first, it's not really good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible to change a variable from public to private.

Answer (score 0):

Use access modifiers (setters, getters)and set private property to a public property.

You cannot change visibility of property.

Comment: For the latest PHP versions you can with Reflection. Not that it is advisable :) I only use this during my unit tests to temporary read the value of a property of a framework or something.

Comment: false, you can. See the reflection manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php