# Can class default public variables be defined dynamically from an array in php?

Tags: php, class, properties, mutators

I have a event class that i am using to insert/update data into my database. Is there a way that i can create the public variables from my db_fields array so that i am not having to duplicate the data?

This is my current structure which works...

```
class event{
    protected static $table_name='tName';
    protected static $db_fields = array('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5');

    public $field1;
    public $field2;
    public $field3;
    public $field4;
    public $field5;
}
```

I would like to have something like this..

```
class event{
    protected static $table_name='tName';
    protected static $db_fields = array('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5');

    function __construct() {
        create_public_vars_here($db_fields);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
class event{

    protected static $table_name='tName';
    protected static $db_fields = array('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5');

    function __construct() {
        foreach (self::$db_fields as $var) {
            $this->$var = $whateverDefaultValue;
        }
        // After the foreach loop, you'll have a bunch of properties of this object with the variable names being the string values of the $db_fiels.
        // For example, you'll have $field1, $field2, etc and they will be loaded with the value $whateverDefaultValue (probably want to set it to null).
    }

}
```

Comment: Very nice. Is there a way to explicitly declare the variable "public" instead of relying on the default behavior or non-declared variables being public?

Comment: @L0j1k I believe it's possible, but I haven't really done that before. Someone has said that Reflection can do this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php Check out this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274348/programmatically-change-variable-from-public-to-private

Comment: So if I use this the variables are public by default without declaring them so?

Comment: I'm shocked (and kind of disturbed) that PHP lets you do that. +1 for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @User1718435: Meaning, you will be chastised by other programmers for relying on behavior of programming languages that do not explicitly do things. ESPECIALLY if those other programmers are maintaining your code.

Comment: The reason for that is because relying on this kind of implicit functionality makes some errors very, very hard to find. You are obfuscating your code by doing it, so it's best not to.

Comment: @user1718435 I agree with L0j1k. I wouldn't write this class in this way, either. Not sure why you want to do it this way (I'd probably set $db_fields as an associative array and write a setter method that deals with the associated values). However, if you HAVE to do this way, it's one way to do it, but it's not necessary the best way.

Comment: I 'm not sure what functionality exactly is "implicit" here. You can set any new property on any object at runtime in PHP; you can also do that in way too many other languages. It might be a good idea, or it might not be.

Comment: Uhm...... The "implicit" behavior of relying on a class variable being "public" without declaration? That?

Comment: I hate to do this, but i have to go this route for the time being. Thanks for your help.. I have already put this to use. Hopefully none of you will be maintaining my code for awhile.. LOL

Answer (score 2):

You can use magic setters / getters:

```
class event{

    protected static $table_name='tName';
    protected static $db_fields = array('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5');

    public function __get($key)
    {

        if(!in_array($key, static::$db_fields))
            throw new Exception( $key . " doesn't exist.");

        return $this -> $key;

    }

    public function __set($key, $value)
    {

        if(!in_array($key, static::$db_fields))
            throw new Exception( $key . " doesn't exist.");

        $this -> $key = $value;

    }   

}
```

This way you are sure not to hit values outside your list:

```
$event -> field1 = 'hello';  // --> OK
$event -> field17 = 'hello'; // --> Exception: field17 doesn't exist

echo $event -> field1;  // --> OK
echo $event -> field17; // --> Exception: field17 doesn't exist
```

As for having an explicit public variable declaration in your code, you have no need as long as you don't have to iterate over your objects - but in this case you'd implement [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface based on your static field.

Answer (score 0):

Use mutators:

```
class event{
  protected static $table_name='tName';
  protected static $db_fields = array('field1','field2','field3','field4','field5');

  function getVars($var) {
    if(!in_arrary($this->db_fields[$var])) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return $this->db_fields[$var];
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can access it like this:

```
$eventObject->getVars('field3');
```

Or, if you don't create an object out of the class:

```
event::getVars('field3');
```

EDIT: In the spirit of complicating things so that you don't have a bounds violation, code added.

Comment: I dunno. That's one way to do it. I just wrote up my answer like this. :P +1